# For open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n,$ does there exists an open exhaustion $\left\{U_k\right\}$ of $U$ such that $d_H(\partial U, \partial U_k)\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a proper open set (not necessarily bounded), I want to know whether there is an open exhaustion $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $U$ (i.e. each $U_k\subset U$ is open and proper in $U$, $\partial U\cap\partial U_k=\varnothing,$ $U_k\subset U_{k+1}$ and $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty U_k=U$) such that
$$d_H(\partial U, \partial U_k)\to 0(k\to\infty)\tag{1}$$
where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff distance between sets, that's: for $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^n, d_H(A,B)$ is defined by
$$d_H(A,B)=\max\left\{\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B), \sup_{b\in B}d(b,A)\right\}$$
($d(a,B)$ is the usual distance, i.e. $d(a,B)=\inf_{b\in B}|a-b|.$)

I have solved it when $U$ is bounded, in this case $\partial U$ is compact, so if we set
$$U_k=\left\{x\in U:d(x,\partial U)>\frac{1}{k}\right\}\tag{2}$$
it's easy to see that $\{U_k\}$ is an open exhaustion. To see $(1)$ holds, note that
$$\sup_{x\in\partial U_k}d(x,\partial U)\leq \frac{1}{k}\tag{3}$$
so it suffices to show
$$\sup_{x\in\partial U}d(x,\partial U_k)\to 0\tag{4}$$
if $(4)$ is false, note that $\sup_{x\in\partial U}d(x,\partial U_k)$ is monotonically decreasing on $k,$ so there is $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in\partial U}d(x,\partial U_k)>\varepsilon_0,\qquad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}^+$$
for each $k$, there is $x_k\in\partial U$ such that $d(x_k,\partial U_k)\geq \varepsilon_0,$ by compactness of $\partial U$ we may assume WLOG $x_k\to x_0\in \partial U,$ so $d(x_0,\partial U_k)\geq\varepsilon_0,\forall k.$ Now consider the ball $B_{\varepsilon_0/2}(x_0),$ it will intersect $U,$ say at $y_0,$ take $k$ large enough so that $B_{1/k}(y_0)\subset\subset U,$ so $d(y_0,\partial U)> \frac{1}{k},$ which implies $y_0\in U_k,$ thus $d(x_0,\partial U_k)\leq |x_0-y_0|<\frac12\varepsilon_0,$ absurd!

But when $U$ is unbounded, the above argument cannot apply and by considering
$$U=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x,y>0,y<\frac1x\right\}\tag{5}$$
we find $(2)$ does not work in unbounded case, so how can I handle the unbounded case or is it false when $U$ is unbounded? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @MW Oh yes! I mistyped it and have corrected it now.